# compiling C++ console application in linux

Tags: c++, linux, matlab

I have generated a c++ shared library and integrated it with a C++ console application which is called from php. I was trying this on my windows os and it works perfect. Now I have to transfer it into a linux web server. I know I have to compile the c++ console application in linux again to run it and may be generate the c++ shared library also. I am new to the linux os, how can I compile the c++ console application in linux server assigning all the additional library,include files,header files generated from the c++ shared library like we do in Visual Studio? Any link regarding this will be highly appreciated. As the shared library is from matlab I should also assign the matlab include files and libraries ewhile compiling the c++ console application.

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of what files you have - or show a makefile or something? I'm absolutely sure this question can be answered, but without further detail, it will be things like "use -I to indicate include directories", which may not be what you need.

Comment: Regarding the matlab stuff, be aware that windows dll cannot be used on linux, you have to use .a (static libraries) or .so (dynamic libraries) that play the same role in linux than the .lib and .dll.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to get a Linux [port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting) of your matlab made library, which might involve getting matlab installed and working on Linux (and a little testing & debugging).

When your lib is ready, port your console application also (debugging et. all), open a terminal then:-

```
gcc -Wall console_app.c /path/to/your/libFromMatlab.a -o console_app
```

If your console app's source spans multiple files, you may want to consider using an IDE like [code::blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads) or use a makefile to simplfy your work.

Add your "libFromMatlab.so" (notice the .so  vs the .a above) location to the library path (or copy it to where the others reside), then make sure your console_app has executable flag set.

**NB:Developing on any platform other than the target platform without cross-compiling is equivalent to playing Russian roulette...only less lethal.**

-----**EDIT**------
I also came across [this article](http://www.icg.tugraz.at/Members/pmroth/projects/m2c/HowToCompile.pdf) and thought section 4 may be of some value.